# Differ from somebody doing something

Tags: phrases

> Like his father, Alfred Nobel was imaginative and inventive, but *differed from him showing more financial sense*. He was quick to see industrial openings for his scientific inventions and invested in over 80 companies in 20 different countries.

Source: [Alfred Nobel, a Man of Contrasts](http://iliqom.persiangig.com/.5hS9eAJraj/document/inter3unit7passage.pdf)

Is this structure correct?

[image]

Comment: Sure. "...(but differed from him) (*by* showing more financial sense). He was different from his father, because he had more financial sense.

Comment: @user3169: How about putting a comma after _him_ -- _differed from him, showing more financial sense_? Does it correct it?

Comment: I would just use *by* as I wrote. English likes to leave out implied words, and I think that is the case here. You might get away with a comma, but so many already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use "but differed from him **in** showing....".

A comma wouldn't be my choice there because the sentence is already chopped into small pieces, so if I wanted to use a comma I'd have to re-write it a bit to get rid of at least one of the other commas.  English used to use, as German still does, commas to separate clauses.  But that's fallen out of style in 20th-c. English.